# How do I delete just the videos from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video, ios

So I'm running out of space on my iPhone (iOS 4.3) and the quickest thing to do is delete the videos that are already backed up in iPhoto.

How can I do this quickly? That is, without scanning through the 4000+ items in my Camera Roll and looking for the video icons.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, I'm not looking to delete *all* the videos, just enough to free up some space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for the self-answer, but I found a way to do it quickly using just the iPhone and no third-party software.

In iOS 4.3, do the following:

1. Open Camera.app
2. Click the photo thumbnail to view the photo library
3. Click Camera Roll to view all photos
4. There's a capsule button at the top that says 'All|Photos|Videos'. Select videos
5. Press the Export icon - you can now tap on videos to select them before hitting Delete.

Not sure why this functionality is not available from Photos.app, but there you go.  Thanks for all the other answers.

Comment: don't worry about the self-answer... that's actually encouraged to do it - as long as there's no other answer, such in this case.

Comment: great answer!  i know about the camera.app allowing you to show only videos, but didn't realize that the "share" button would also allow you to delete your selections.  big help! thx

Answer (score 1):

You can in iTunes on the Photos tab de-select "Include videos" - then all videos on your iPhone will be deleted - when you do a sync.

Otherwise you need to manually delete the videos one by one from your iPhone.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want all videos to be deleted - just enough to free up some space.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to delete individual videos from the iPhone and but not in iTunes. I use a program called iPhone Explorer (PC or MAC). Once installed, connect the iPhone to computer and iPhone Explorer should find it. Drill down to <100APPLE>. That is where I find the videos listed.
Good luck.

Comment: You understand the question correctly. I'm going to check out Phone Explorer, thanks. But also check out the solution I found buried in camera.app.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer that means you must hook your iPhone up to a box running OS  X.
You can use Image Capture in OS X to select individual photos/video on your iDevice, and import/delete them. You can sort the files by "kind", that would show videos as "mp4", "mov" and so on.