# Purchased tv shows on my iphone, how do i take them off?

Tags: data-synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove videos from iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35926/how-do-i-remove-videos-from-iphone)

I bought a couple tv shows while on my Iphone. So i plug my phone into my PC and now they are on my computer too. How can i take them off of my phone after i watched them and just leave them on my Itunes? They are taking up too much space on my phone and they don't need to be on it since i have already watched them.

Answer (score 1):

Open iTunes. When your device is plugged in, click on it in iTunes. Then, click the TV shows tab at the top. It will say "Automatically include all episodes of all shows". Click where it says "all shows" and change it to "selected shows," then deselect the shows that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the iPhone anymore. But I remember that the options for what to sync can be edited when...

1. ...you connect the iPhone to the computer.
2. In iTunes, click on the iPhone in the sidebar.
3. Then look out for the options at the top photos, music,... Once you click on one of those options, you can decide what to sync an what not.

Answer (score 0):

Open the list in videos on your iPhone, and swipe across them to bring up the delete option.

Hit delete.

They will be removed from the phone but not from your computers iTunes.