# I want to delete some videos downloaded from iTunes onto my iPad

Tags: ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove videos from iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35926/how-do-i-remove-videos-from-iphone)

I have downloaded some videos from iTunes onto my iPad. Now I want to delete them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2393960?start=0&tstart=0

> Slide finger over video title and tap delete button

or

> Tap and hold video title and tap delete icon